# "Unsupported hash type" error w/ Python 2.6.5 and django framework

Tags: python, django

My registration form is throwing a ValueError during `form.save()` in my custom registration form's password field.

Here are the exception details (copied from http://www.pastie.org/1299144):

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.2.206:8080/register/
Django Version: 1.1.1
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'mysite.registration',
 'mysite.profiles',
 'mysite.epw',
 'mysite.remember_me',
 'mysite.avatar',
 'mysite.django_documents',
 'mysite.inlines',
 'mysite.blog',
 'mysite.forum',
 'tagging']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'mysite.remember_me.views.AutoLogout')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  48.                 response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/karthik/Desktop/EPW_LOCAL/mysite/../mysite/epw/views.py" in register
  1538.             new_user = form.save(request)
File "/home/karthik/Desktop/EPW_LOCAL/mysite/../mysite/epw/form.py" in save
  169.                                                                     profile_callback=profile_callback)
File "/home/karthik/Desktop/EPW_LOCAL/mysite/../mysite/registration/models.py" in create_inactive_user
  110.         registration_profile = self.create_profile(new_user)
File "/home/karthik/Desktop/EPW_LOCAL/mysite/../mysite/registration/models.py" in create_profile
  145.         salt = hashlib.new(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py" in __hash_new
  101.         return __get_builtin_constructor(name)(string)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/hashlib.py" in __get_builtin_constructor
  80.     raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"

Exception Type: ValueError at /register/
Exception Value: unsupported hash type
```

pls could any one resolve this.
thanks

Comment: Could you please reformat your question? Use the 101010 button to mark code blocks, speak in full English, and don't make everything bold.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're trying to implement your own registration framework with it. What's wrong with the existing one? I think you should read more about the Django framework generally and go through the tutorial.

Looking at that traceback, the problem is in the line `hashlib.new(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]`. (Get familiar with looking at tracebacks and working out what the issue is, you'll find you need to often when you make a mistake.)

`help(hashlib.new)` shows this:

```
__hash_new(name, string='')
    new(name, string='') - Return a new hashing object using the named algorithm;
    optionally initialized with a string.
```

The "named algorithm" should be md5, sha1, sha256, etc. (See `help(hashlib)` for the list, and also how you should use e.g. `hashlib.md5()` instead of `hashlib.new('md5')`.)

Answer (score 1):

`haslib.new()` expects a hashing algorithm name (e.g. "md5", "sha1" etc.) as the first parameter. You're passing in a random string.

Answer (score 0):

when the password is saving at the time instead of  **hashlib** i use **sha** cryptographic alog that works fine